# Convert Simple Obj-C into Python

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, ios

I have an app that I've been working on, but now I need to get this line converted into Python.

```
return (highValue > 21) ? lowValue : highValue;
```

The above says if the number highValue is greater than 21, return lowValue, and if it is lower than 21, return highValue. How can I convert this into Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```
>>> highvalue = 25
>>> lowvalue = 21
>>> def myfunc():
...     return lowvalue if highvalue>21 else highvalue
...
>>> myfunc()
21
>>>
```

Also take a look here [python-ternary-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator).

Comment: This is it! Thank you! Now I know what these things are called!